# How can I use sigma index notation to formlate an equation combining the discrete series of trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry, index-notation

How can I use sigma index notation to formulate an equation combining the discrete series of trigonometric functions?

For $n = 1$:  $f=\sin (\pi-\theta_1)$

For $n = 2$:  $f=\sin (\pi-\theta_1) + \sin (2\pi-(\theta_1 + \theta_2))$

For $n = 3$:  $f=\sin (\pi-\theta_1) + \sin (2\pi-(\theta_1 + \theta_2)) + \sin (3\pi-(\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3))$

Attempt:

For an arbitrary value of $n$, where 1 < n < 3: $$f = \sum_{1}^{n} \sin(i\cdot\pi−\theta_i)$$

Help me correct the equation please?

Comment: What you have written is correct.

Comment: Indeed
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sin{(k\pi - \theta_k)}
$$
is what you're doing there.

Comment: @Jayen: I formatted your mathematics using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409). Please double-check that my changes match your intention. ... I'll note that I didn't "fix" the minor issues with your final summation notation, namely: (1) you should have an "$i=$" in order to declare the summation index; and (2) you want $n$ instead of $3$ as the upper limit. (That was probably a typo.) BTW: "$j$" or "$k$" is probably a better summation index, since "$i$" could get confused with the imaginary unit (which eventually gets used a great deal with trig functions).

Comment: @Blue Thank you for the correction which indeed matches the actual meaning. Thank you for stating MathJax and helping. However, I did not write it correctly, can you check it again please?

Comment: After the edit, you have changed
$$
\theta_i \quad \rightarrow \quad \sum_{j=1}^i \theta_j
$$
So you just have to write that in the place of $\theta_i$

Comment: Thank you @MattiP.